# How do I get the PK when seeding data using the entity framework, using multiple conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6.1

Using the Entity-Framework-6 in combination whit MVC-5 and Identity-framework-2. I wanted to find the primary key from the first seed, and inserting the found key in the second seed. I am using multiple conditions to find the key, but somehow my Lambda expession is not working or is not correctly written.

What am I missing?

Staring Here: /migrations/configurations.cs

I am using this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/24936095/2910930 as base for the rest of my seed.

```
protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    bool itWorks = WriteReferenceData(context);
    base.Seed(context);
}

private bool WriteReferenceData(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
{
    DbContextTransaction transaction = null;
    bool succeeded = false;
    try
    {
        transaction = ctx.Database.BeginTransaction();

        CreateDetails(ctx);
        CreateRooms(ctx);

        ctx.SaveChanges();
        transaction.Commit();
        succeeded = true;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         if (transaction != null) { transaction.Rollback(); transaction.Dispose(); }
         succeeded = false;
     }
     return succeeded;
}
```

In the first seed I wil insert multiple records, the PK is DB generated. When I run this method the records are inserted correctly and the PK are generated.

```
// FIRST SEED
private void CreateDetails(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
{
  var Details = new List<Detail>
  {
      new Detail { MaxUsers = 1, RoomName = "WorkRoom"},
      new Detail { MaxUsers = 2, RoomName = "WorkRoom"},
      new Detail { MaxUsers = 3, RoomName = "PlayRoom"}
  };
  Details.ForEach(s => ctx.Detail.AddOrUpdate(p => p.DetailID, s));
  ctx.SaveChanges();
}

// SECOND SEED
private void CreateRooms(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
{
    // THIS IS NOT WORKING CORRECTLY
    Int16 ID = ctx.Detail
                  .Single(x => 
                      x.RoomName == "WorkRoom" &&   
                      x.MaxUsers == 2).DetailID;

    var Rooms = new List<Room>
    {
        // 1 person
        new Room { RoomID = "X-16", DetailID = ID}
        new Room { RoomID = "X-17", DetailID = ID}
    };
    Rooms.ForEach(s => ctx.Room.AddOrUpdate(p => p.RoomID, s));
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: EF will fix up the foreign key values for you if you add the children to the navigation property (collection of children) of the parent.

Comment: What is the relationship between `Room` and `Detail`? Why is there a `DetailID` property in `Room` and `RoomName` in `Detail`?

Comment: @keith: Room and detail have a many to one relation. I got a lot of rooms and they have 1 detail. As you can see is the DetailKey a FK in the Rooms table. And EF will not automatically fix the foreign key becasuse these are bound by specific conditions.

Comment: I see, `RoomName` is not intended to be an attribute of a `Room` but of a  `Detail`.

Comment: `ctx.Detail.AddOrUpdate(p => p.DetailID, s)` looks suspect. In samples they are using natural keys to find rows which may be updated, not a surrogate key. Can you confirm that there are three rows in the table after the first `SaveChanges()` ?

Comment: @keith: Yes, Roomname is a colomn in the Detail table. And Yes I inserted 3 colomns in 3 rows. The table design is working (thats not the issue). But something is not correct in my Lambda expression (reading the DetailID) (and debugging is a frustrating job when your using the Seed method).

Comment: PS a better name for roomname would be roomtype :)

Answer (score 0):

Afther reading alot about linq and Lambda the answer is much more easier then I tought.

```
var detail = ctx.Detail.Where(x => x.DetailRoomName == "Patientroom" && x.MaxUsers == 1);

int detailID = detail.Single().DetailID;

var Rooms = new List<Room>
{
    // 1 person
    new Room { RoomID = "X-16", DetailID = detailID }
    new Room { RoomID = "X-17", DetailID = detailID }
};
```